# "Для того(,) чтобы", "перед тем(,) как", "несмотря на то(,) что" и т. д

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, предлоги, союзы, местоимения

1. Достаточно ли обосновано право на существование написанных **без запятой** выше приведённых союзов, если они произошли от **местоимений+союзов** "то, чтобы", "то, как", "то, что" соответственно, которые **всегда пишутся с запятой**?
2. Есть, конечно, правила для этих и подобных союзов, касаемых запятой. Однако я ставлю там запятую всегда.

Comment: Вчем смысл вопроса? Приведите хотя бы правило, которое хотите обсудить, потом будете о каком-то праве рассуждать.

Comment: Однако, невзирая на правила, их много кто соблюдает... Проблема.

Comment: @Мимоходов 1. Перед тем, как назвать полное правило, Вы подумаете насчёт того, чтобы его ожидать/не ~, а для того, чтобы принять решение насчёт ожидания, я назову неполное (по памяти) правило и отвечу на Ваш вопрос о смысле моего вопроса. 2. Смысл моего вопроса в недоумении того, что из-за каких-то предлогов пунктуация стала того.

Comment: @Мимоходов 3. С данным правилом я не очень согласен. По памяти оно вот: если составной союз в начале, он не расчлен.; если не там, расчлен.; если логическое ударение на сопоставительное слово ("то"…), или что-то заставляет падать туда, расчлен..

Comment: 1. Может, это вообще забава Розенталя, которая случайно выложилась на весь люд и стала почти общепризнанной (я эту нетривиальность не признаю)?!

Comment: @ХонКингКонгКорольКириллист300 Ничем не могу помочь. Если вы несогласны с правилом, обращайтесь в РАН.

Comment: @Мимоходов 1. А там можно дистанционно обращаться? (XD) Или только идти? А то я в Южной Корее.

Answer (score 1):

**Расчленение составного союза – это не только тема постановки запятых, но и грамматическая тема.** Все СПП делятся на две группы: в первом случае придаточные относятся **к опорному слову** в главном предложении (обычно при местоименной связи); во втором случае придаточные относятся **ко всему предложению** (обычно при союзной связи).

Вам  кажется, что вы расчленяете или не расчленяете составной союз по Розенталю, а на самом деле **вы делаете принципиальный выбор между двумя типами предложений.**

Рассмотрим пример: **Раскольников молчал и не сопротивлялся, несмотря на то что  чувствовал в себе достаточно сил приподняться.**  Достоевский не расчленяет сложный союз, то есть придаточное относится ко всему главному предложению. В этом случае  самостоятельность и значимость главного предложения повышаются (в принципе мы можем вообще убрать придаточное предложение).

Но этот союз можно и расчленить: **Раскольников молчал и не сопротивлялся несмотря на тО,  что  чувствовал в себе достаточно сил приподняться.**

Теперь мы имеем взаимобусловленную связь между придаточным и главным предложениями, они зависят друг от друга, поэтому **статус придаточного стал выше**. Придаточное относится к местоименному указательному слову, включенному в главную часть.

Расчленение союза во многом зависит **от позиции придаточного:** обычно в препозиции составной союз не расчленяется, а в постпозиции расчленяется. В нашем примере  нормой было бы  нерасчленение союза, но **если автор принял другое решение, то это сделано именно для повышения статуса главного предложения.**

Comment: 1. Я, кстати, данный вопрос завёл ввиду того, что даже сами местоимения+союзы "то, что" и "то, чтобы" перестали расчленять, а некоторые стали их писать слитно: рукалицо!

Comment: 2. Я не зря провёл аналогию этим союзам: назвал местоим.+союзы "то, что", "то, чтобы"…. Ведь "несмотря на то, что" и "то, что" - это же совершенно однокоренные словосочетания и основной смысл имеют один и тот же, чтобы на них разные правила работали. Вот не можем мы сказать "Спасибо, за то что помогли", поскольку запятая не там, где надо, а ведь очень похоже, будто "за то" - часть союза. Или вот, "Я не надеюсь, на то что наберу 1М подписчиков за 7 месяцев, - я просто уверен, если кучу тегов напихать в видео для того, дабы взломать алгоритмы ты-трубы" также нельзя сказать: верно "на то, что".

Comment: Здесь надо знать вид придаточного. Местоименная часть может вообще не соединяться с союзной (я надеюсь на то,  что..., изъяснительное придаточное); союз  следствия так что вообще не может расчленяться, а если его расчленитЬ, то это будет другое придаточное ( образа действия + следствие, увлекся так, что всё забыл). И наконец факультативное расчленение уже рассмотренных союзов. Поэтому без знаний грамматики в этой теме не обойтись.

Comment: 1. Да, я не отрицаю существование "так что", "так как", ибо написанные с запятой их аналоги уже имеют другой смысл, в отличие от "для того(,) чтобы", была бы там запятая или нет.